# Entity Framework Core errors when using local DB

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core

I'm trying EF Core and I'm using the example in this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

With SQLite, everything works ok, when I try to do the same with `Microsoft.FrameWorkCore.SqlServer`, I run the `Add-Migration` and it finishes ok, then I set the UWP app as start up project and after I get the following error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'LocalDB is not supported on this platform.

Where the UWP app is trying to create the DB, path and folder?

My sqllocaldb information is the following

```
C:\>sqllocaldb
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Express LocalDB Command Line Tool
Version 13.0.1601.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Usage: SqlLocalDB operation [parameters...]


C:\>sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            13.1.4001.0
Shared name:
Owner:              
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    
Instance pipe name:

C:\>sqllocaldb i ProjectsV13
Name:               ProjectsV13
Version:            13.1.4001.0
Shared name:
Owner:              
Auto-create:        No
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    
Instance pipe name:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UWP SqlClient does not support named pipes, use the free SQL Server Express and enable tcp connections from it.

Comment: I did that now i m getting>  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Failed to generate SSPI context. My connection string is  = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Server=.;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;"

Comment: Any thoughts? I know that the connection string is correct because if I test it with a .NET Core 2.1 console project it works fine, however using UWP project throws the error:
Failed to generate SSPI context.
ErrorCode=NoCredentials

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Besides enabling the TCP protocol you have to set the 'Enterprise Authentication' capability in the Package.appxmanifest. Otherwise 'Trusted_Connection=True' doesn't work.
From:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22890#issuecomment-333305084